# How to pass values between forms in c# windows application?

Tags: c#

I have two forms A and B. Form A is the default start up form of the application.
I do some stuffs in Form A and i then i want to run my Form B parallel and then pass
a parameter to a method in Form B from Form A.

How ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ian has given some example code, but I'd like to make a broader point:

**UI classes are just classes.**

How would you pass a value from one object to another object if they *weren't* part of the user interface? You'd have a reference from one to the other, and call a method or set a property. The same exact thing holds for user interface objects.

I mention this because it's something that comes up a lot. Whenever you ask yourself: "How do I do *X* with forms?" try asking yourself the same question but with plain old classes. Often the answer will be exactly the same.

Of course there are *some* differences for user interface classes - particularly with threading - but for an awful lot of cases, it really helps if you just think of them as normal classes.

Comment: +1 That's a good point Skeet. Shall remember that for the future.

Answer (score 6):

FormA should construct/hold an instance to FormB. Obviously the method on FormB needs to be public, change the type of object used in CallMethodOnFormB to the correct type too.

```
public class FormA
{
   private FormB fB;

   public void CreateFormB()
   { 
      // This shows the form in parallel.
      this.fB = new FormB();
      this.fB.Show();
   }

   public void CallMethodOnFormB(object value)
   {
      this.fB.RunSomeFunction(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Public or internal, of course. I suspect we (I'm definitely including myself in this) make a lot of things public that should really just be internal.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Often however when I'm working with forms I'm trying to create generic ones that can be re-used in different assemblies, and therefore I have a tendency to use Public for Forms (or UI classes in general). Other classes I will tend to only make them public if they really need to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize EventAggregator pattern, if you don't want to couple your forms.

Some reading:

- http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html
- http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/07/21/braindump-on-the-event-aggregator-pattern.aspx
- http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/07/23/how-i-m-using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-in-storyteller.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, another approach would be to introduce a global instance of a class (a **singleton**), which can hold stuff that is to be shared between several forms/classes of your application.

For instance, if you have a form where the user can define his settings/preferences, you could store that data in a singleton. All other classes and forms of your application can then access/read these settings from the same singleton instance.

Here's a very basic example of a singleton:

```
public class MySettings
{
  // the one and only instace (the singleton):
  public static readonly MySettings Instance = new MySettings();
  private MySettings() {} // private constructor

  public int SomeNumber { get; set; }
  public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can access set/get the properties of MySetting from any other class/form in your application, e.g:

in PreferencesForm.cs:

```
//read the user's input and store it in the settings
MySettings.Instance.SomeNumber = txtNumber.Value;
```

in SomeOtherForm.cs:

```
//read the user's setting and use it
int theNumber = MySettings.Instance.SomeNumber;
// do something with theNumber
```