# Showing Class Properties to TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a class named UserIdentity

```
class UserIdentity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Gender {get; set;}
    public string Age {get; set;}
    public string Department {get;set;}

}
```

I am trying to have a button to save the user data,

```
    private void UserID_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserIdentity user = new UserIdentity()
        {
            Name = textUserName.Text,
            Age = textUserAge.Text,
            Gender = textUserGender.Text,
            Department = textUserDepartment.Text

        };
    }
```

it worked perfectly when I show the user data directly from the textboxt form,

```
    private void ShowUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayName.Text = textUserName.Text,
        DisplayAge.Text = textUserAge.Text,
        DisplayGender.Text = textUserGender.Text,
        DisplayDepartment.Text = textUserDepartment.Text,

    }
```

But I'm trying to show user data from an object, but it gives me "the name 'user' does not exist in the current context"

```
    private void ShowUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayName.Text = user.Name;
        DisplayAge.Text = user.Age;
        DisplayGender.Text =  user.Gender;
        DisplayDepartment.Text =  user.Department;

    }
```

this doesn't work either

```
    private void ShowUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DisplayName.Text = UserIdentity.Name;
        DisplayAge.Text = UserIdentity.Age;
        DisplayGender.Text =  UserIdentity.Gender;
        DisplayDepartment.Text =  UserIdentity.Department;

    }
```

how do I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205195/how-to-pass-values-between-forms-in-c-sharp-windows-application

Answer (score 0):

Take user to global:

```
      UserIdentity user;
private void UserID_Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        user = new UserIdentity()
        {
            Name = textUserName.Text,
            Age = textUserAge.Text,
            Gender = textUserGender.Text,
            Department = textUserDepartment.Text

        };
    }
```