# Forms not communicating correctly

Tags: c#, forms, communication

I've been trying to make multiform programs for quite some time now, but I run into the same 2 problems again and again:

1. Form2 (Or however you call it) treats **already set** variables as *null*
2. Form1 doesn't accept, when Form2 changes a variable from Form1

It's been so annoying lately, that I've decided to ask here, what I may (or may not) be doing wrong. Here's my quick reproductuion - A program, where you can set a given value using another form:

*valueForm*

```
public partial class valueForm : Form
{
    public int value;
    private changeValueForm change;
    public valueForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value = 2;
        valueLabel.Text = value.ToString();
        change = new changeValueForm();
    }

    private void change_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        change.Show();
    }

    private void updatin_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        valueLabel.Text = change.thisValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

*changeValueForm*

```
public partial class changeValueForm : Form
{
    private valueForm valueForm;
    public int thisValue;
    private string[] digits = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
    public changeValueForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void changeValueForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        valueForm = new valueForm();
        thisValue = valueForm.value;
        valueBox.Text = thisValue.ToString();
    }

    private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (digits.Contains(valueBox.Text.ToString()))
        {
            thisValue = Int32.Parse(valueBox.Text);
            valueForm.value = thisValue;
        }
    }
}
```

So, summa summarum, what is wrong with this code?

**P.S.** [How to pass values between forms in c# windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205195/how-to-pass-values-between-forms-in-c-sharp-windows-application) Might have hepled with the 1. problem, but `valueForm` still doesn't accept changes made in `changeValueForm` - It just stays as it was.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass values between forms in c# windows application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205195/how-to-pass-values-between-forms-in-c-sharp-windows-application)

Comment: Yes yes, I know. I just couldn't come up with any better tags!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new instance of `valueForm` here:

```
private void changeValueForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    valueForm = new valueForm();
```

You should pass to your `changeValueForm` instance reference to your existed `valueForm` and use it.

For example this can be done when you're creating your `changeValueForm`, like `change = new changeValueForm(this);`.

In this case you also need to and changeValueForm constructor to

```
public changeValueForm(valueForm f)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    valueForm = f;
}
```

Also it it unclear from the code you've posted - when it it suposed to call `updatin_Tick` method and who should call it? I can guess from the method name - it should be some timer - but there is not any timer declared in your code.

Comment: Put a parameter in a control constructor is not trivial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784303/usercontrol-constructor-with-parameters-in-c-sharp especially the Visual Studio Windows Forms Designer will not handle it.

Comment: @Orace You have posted reference to post dated more than 5 years. Modern versions of Visual Studio (for example, VS2012) perfectly handles situation when you have parameterized constructor and have not parameterless one.

Comment: good to know. Also I work with VS2010. And it's not dead: https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=Visual%20Studio%202010&Filter=FilterNO

Answer (score 0):

It is a common situation. In your `changeValueForm` you create a new instance of the `valueForm`. This new instance has nothing in common (a part from being the same class) with the initial form. It is a totally different form. So, when you set properties to the instance created inside the `changeValueForm` you are setting the properties of a form that is not visible. (Just try to call `Show()` on that instance).

The easiest way to fix the problem is passing the instance of the initial `valueForm` to the `changeValueForm` created by your code. 
Usually this is done in the constructor, but could also passed using a public custom property of the valueChangeForm class.

USING THE CONSTRUCTOR

```
public partial class changeValueForm : Form
{
    private valueForm valueForm;
    ....

    public changeValueForm(valueForm currentInstance)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        valueForm = currentInstance;
    }
```

Of course when you build your changeValueForm you call

```
public partial class valueForm : Form
{
    public int value;
    private changeValueForm change;
    public valueForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        value = 2;
        valueLabel.Text = value.ToString();

        // pass this instance to the changeValueForm
        change = new changeValueForm(this);
    }
```

USING A PROPERTY

```
public partial class changeValueForm : Form
{
    private valueForm valueForm;

    public changeValueForm ClientCaller 
    { get { return valueForm}; 
      set { valueForm = value};
    }....


public partial class valueForm : Form
{
    ...
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ....
        change = new changeValueForm();
        change.ClientCaller = this;
    }
```

Comment: Put a parameter in a control constructor is not trivial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784303/usercontrol-constructor-with-parameters-in-c-sharp especially the Visual Studio Windows Forms Designer will not handle it.

Comment: There is no problem in passing a parameter to a form constructor. The article linked is relative to UserControls that requires a parameterless constructor to be used/dropped in a designer surface